# Grammarly automatically adding padding to my body tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently hosting a website at GitHub, but one thing I noticed was that the Grammarly Chrome extension automatically adds a padding-top attribute to my body tag.

```
<body data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="14.1028.0" data-gr-ext-installed="" data-gr-ext-disabled="forever" style="padding-top: 72px;">
```

This creates an unnecessary space on my website. I know removing the extension is an answer, but I can't force my readers to do the same. Is there anything I can do to prevent it from doing so?

Comment: Try adding a class to your body like <body class="no-top-padding"> and in your css file add .no-top-padding{padding-top: 0 !important}. Note !important is the key. That will override your padding-top by grammerly.

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene Damn, that actually worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As @AlaksandarJesusGene mentioned, adding a class *.no-top-padding* with

```
.no-top-padding{padding-top: 0 !important}
```

in the CSS file worked out!

Comment: in my case, it was padding right.. I basically just used 
.no-top-padding{
    padding: 0 !important;
}